# Swift - Concatenate Looped Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm just wondering if Concatenating Looped Array, And appending it into single string is possible? Example:

```
var name = ["John","Peter","Damian"] 
var age = ["23","21","25"] 
var occupation = ["Plumber","Carpenter","Painter"]

var names = String()
var ages = String()
var occu = String()
var output = String()

    for var i = 0; i < name.count; i++ {
           names = name[i]
           ages = age[i]
           occu = occupation[i]
}
output = String(format:"%@ is %@Years Old, He's a %@.",names,ages,occu)
println(output) //Damian is 25Years Old, He's a Painter.
```

What if i want to output all Arrays in a single string separated by "," or "And" Example: `Damian is 25 Years Old, He's a Painter AND John is 23....... AND Peter is.........` Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can do it:

```
var name = ["John","Peter","Damian"]
var age = ["23","21","25"]
var occupation = ["Plumber","Carpenter","Painter"]

var names = String()
var ages = String()
var occu = String()
var output = String()
var finalArr = [String]()

for var i = 0; i < name.count; i++ {

    names = name[i]
    ages = age[i]
    occu = occupation[i]
    output = "\(names) is \(ages) Years Old, He's a \(occu)."
    finalArr.append(output)   //append every sentence into finalArr

}
let stringRepresentation = " And ".join(finalArr) // convert finalArr to string.
```

OutPut:

```
John is 23 Years Old, He's a Plumber. And Peter is 21 Years Old, He's a Carpenter. And Damian is 25 Years Old, He's a Painter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift1.2:

```
var name = ["John","Peter","Damian"]
var age = ["23","21","25"]
var occupation = ["Plumber","Carpenter","Painter"]


let output = " AND ".join(
    map(indices(name), {
        "\(name[$0]) is \(age[$0]) Years Old, He's a \(occupation[$0])"
    })
) + "."

println(output)

// John is 23 Years Old, He's a Plumber AND Peter is 21 Years Old, He's a Carpenter AND Damian is 25 Years Old, He's a Painter.
```

Swift2:

```
var name = ["John","Peter","Damian"]
var age = ["23","21","25"]
var occupation = ["Plumber","Carpenter","Painter"]

let output = name.indices.map({
    "\(name[$0]) is \(age[$0]) Years Old, He's a \(occupation[$0])"
}).joinWithSeparator(" AND ") + "."

print(output)
```